# SearchCursor (arcpy.da), accessing data on joined tables

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, cursor

Can you access joined tables through a da.SearchCursor?

I've found documentation to do this with SearchCursor (arcpy), but nothing for the 10.1 data access module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that the join in ArcMap does not persist in an arcpy session. So I needed to create the join in arcpy before accessing the table with a SearchCursor. A simple example:

```
import arcpy
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import format_tb

exoticPath = r"...\Exotic_Species"
protocolsPath=r"...\Treatment_Protocols"

try:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(exoticPath,"exotic")
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(protocolsPath,"protocols")
    arcpy.AddJoin_management("exotic","Species","protocols","CommonName")

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("exotic", ["Exotic_Species.Species","Treatment_Protocols.Priority"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print (row[0], row[1])

except:
        tb = exc_info()[2]
        tbinfo = format_tb(tb)[0]
        pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(exc_info()[1])
        msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
        arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
        arcpy.AddError(msgs)
        print pymsg + "\n"
        print msgs


finally:
    if arcpy.Exists("exotic"):
        arcpy.Delete_management("exotic")
    if arcpy.Exists("protocols"):
        arcpy.Delete_management("protocols")
```

Answer (score 1):

The arcpy.da.*Cursor are functionally equivalent to their arcpy.*Cursor counterpart... some additional niceties (context, more sql),  and lots more speed. see doc for full details: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

When writing new code, always use arcpy.da.Cursors.
If you have critical code that uses old cursors, you may want to switch that code to new cursors.

Comment: I do not think this is an answer to the question.